# How to address a shape drawn on a HTML5 canvas and change its properties?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, createjs, easeljs

I am beginning to explore the HTML5 canvas, and I apologize in advance for the naivety of my question. Using Flash CC, I have generated a canvas with a rectangle on it:

```
(function (lib, img, cjs, ss) {
var p; // shortcut to reference prototypes
// library properties:
lib.properties = {
    width: 550,
    height: 400,
    fps: 24,
    color: "#FFFFFF",
    manifest: []
};
// symbols:
// stage content:
(lib.canvas_test = function() {
    this.initialize();
    // Layer 1
    this.shape = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape.graphics.beginFill().beginStroke("#669966")
    .setStrokeStyle(1,1,1).moveTo(-94,-62).lineTo(94,-62).lineTo(94,62).lineTo(-94,62).closePath();
    this.shape.setTransform(198,136);
    this.shape_1 = new cjs.Shape();
    this.shape_1.graphics.beginFill("#FF933C")
    .beginStroke().moveTo(-94,62).lineTo(-94,-62).lineTo(94,-62).lineTo(94,62).closePath();
    this.shape_1.setTransform(198,136);
    this.addChild(this.shape_1,this.shape);
}).prototype = p = new cjs.Container();
p.nominalBounds = new cjs.Rectangle(378,273,190,126);
})(lib = lib||{}, images = images||{}, createjs = createjs||{}, ss = ss||{});
var lib, images, createjs, ss;
```

Now I am stuck. How can I retrieve (and change) the color of the rectangle using a Javascript function? I had hoped that the shapes would simply be children of the canvas, but this does not seem to be the case.

Comment: Things drawn onto the canvas are just image data - they don't exist as actual entities anywhere, you need to keep track of them yourself.  That said, it appears the code that's been generated is making use of [CreateJS](http://www.createjs.com/), which appears as though it may do some of this object tracking for you (ie `new cjs.Shape()`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The earlier answers are correct about Canvas being basically a bitmap, but EaselJS gives you a retained graphics mode, so you can change properties and update the stage/canvas to reflect them.

You are using Flash export to generate your content, so you should be able to access your elements via the `exportRoot`, which is created in the HTML. This is essentially the Flash "stage", represented by an EaselJS container that is defined by `canvas_test` in your exported library.

```
exportRoot = new lib.canvas_test();
```

You can see in the canvas_test code, each "child" is defined. Any graphics are wrapped in EaselJS `Shape` instances. There are also classes for handling groups (Containers), Bitmaps, Text, and animations (MovieClips).

**Here is your exported code above put added to the stage:
http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/b5me4xa2/**

It is easy to modify shapes once they are created, but you have to define them with that in mind. The Flash export doesn't really provide you this capability, since it just exports everything as a single, chained graphics instructions list. You can however introspect it fairly easily to find the commands you want to modify. **Warning: This requires EaselJS 0.7.0+ in order to work. Earlier versions will not work with this approach**

The demo you provided has a single Rectangle. Unfortunately there is a bug in the current version of Flash that exports it as 2 shapes, one for the stroke, and another for the fill. This example will modify the stroke.

```
var shape = exportRoot.shape; // Access the shape instance that has the stroke
var stroke = shape.graphics._stroke;
stroke.style = "#ff0000"; // Set to red.
```

To do the fill, you can do the same thing on `shape_1`, but affect the `_fill` instead. Here is an [updated sample](http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/b5me4xa2/1/)

You can also access any of the instructions, and affect their properties. You can see a full command list in the [Graphics docs](http://www.createjs.com/docs/easeljs/classes/Graphics.Fill.html) (see the sidebar for the full list). Here is a quick sample modifying the first `moveTo` command on the stroke:

```
var shape = exportRoot.shape;
shape.graphics._activeInstructions[0].x = -110;
```

You can see a sample of that code here: http://jsfiddle.net/lannymcnie/b5me4xa2/2/ -- You will have to modify both fill and stroke to move them both :)

Comment: Just a heads up, this is not a _recommended_ approach, just something that works in this example. If you rely on this, and change your export, it will likely break. For example, the _fill and _stroke _sometimes_ point to the fill and stroke you expect, but might not.

Answer (score 1):

Canvas is basically a bitmap, it has no children.  An SVG works more like you're imagining but a canvas just has pixels.  If you want to change a canvas you're either going to have to go through it and find the pixels, or create a javascript object representing your drawing object (the rectangle), keep it separate from your canvas background, and redraw the the background and object when there are any changes.

[Added]
I'm not familiar with Flash CC, but as pointed out in the comment, perhaps there is some capability there already to do what the commenter and myself are describing - I'm afraid I don't know.

Comment: You are correct, except that this example uses EaselJS (exported from Flash CC), which is the JavaScript object approach you are suggesting.